# "I am done doing something" [Example sentence with "buying]

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Let's say you have just bought the **most expensive** item out of your ''*need to buy*'' list, and by doing so, you felt satisfied because you will **not** have to **worry anymore**. And you say:

> "Finally, I am done buying the **most expensive** thing I needed to buy, and I have **no worries anymore**."

Is this sentence grammatical? Especially relating to the situation I have given?

Comment: You might want to check the [meaning of "altogether"](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/altogether), as your use of it in the title of this post does not convey an identifiable meaning. Maybe you wanted to say, "in the general context of a sentence"? (Or simply "in context")

Comment: Thx. I am editing it.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of further editing your title, because SE is a place for "reusable" questions, and in my view, the part about "being done doing something" is something that could be useful more widely than just the mention of the verb "to buy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**I am done** V+ing something" means that whatever you are describing with the V (verb) was a long process. Buying, however, is a one-time act. One could spend a lot of time *choosing* a product, but the buying itself is not something that could be a lengthy process.

You could say,

> I am done spending so much time on eBay looking for my perfect [something].

(Other examples for "I am done with": "I'm done putting up with this nonsense" (It means you have been putting up with something for a long time), "I'm done questioning and doubting myself," "I'm done wasting time on social networks", etc.)

Regarding your example, if you want to talk about the act of buying, it's enough to use Present Perfect:

> I have finally bought the most expensive thing I needed to buy.

The phrase "I have no worries anymore" is perfectly grammatical. It's just that I don't see how not having a very expensive thing could be a cause for worrying. But that is a matter of personal philosophy :) A good phrase to use alongside "having finally bought something" is:

> I'm all set now.

It means having everything you need and being prepared for anything that comes your way. Webster's Learner's Dictionary [defines this meaning of "set"](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/set) as "ready or prepared for something", with an example, "If we win the lottery, we'll be set for life. [=we will have everything we need for the rest of our lives]".

So, for example, if you buy a house, you are all set in the sense that you don't have to look for apartments or pay someone rent any longer.

Comment: But isn't it a kind of splitting hairs while imposing extreme correctness as well, the one which is seldom exercised in real life? If by buying you only mean the moment when a customer pays money for the goods then technically it's correct. But it's ridiculous as I think. If I am in a shop and called on the phone, can't I say "I am busy buying things" because technically I am not performing the act of payment?